# Changing the blue color of select box in html

Tags: html, css

I would like to display a different color on hovering of the dropdown in a select option irrespective of the default blue color. Can it be possible using CSS?

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover pseudo class for this purpose. like this

```
select:hover {
  background: #fff2a8;
}
```